# How do you make a specific role able to use a slash command in Nextcord?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, nextcord

How do you make a specific role able to use a slash command in Nextcord?

I have found using `@command.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)` doesn't work when using slash command in Nextcord eg:

```
@bot.slash_command(description="Hello")
@command.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def hi(interaction : Interaction):
    await interaction.send("Hello!")
```

I have tested this using alt accounts without the appropriate permissions and the command still works.

Is this a Nextcord bug or is there a different way to do this using slash commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For slash commands, it's in `application_checks`. It seems.

```
from nextcord.ext import application_checks

@bot.slash_command()
@application_checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def testperms(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('You can manage messages.')
```

[Reference](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/application_checks/index.html?highlight=has_permissions#nextcord.ext.application_checks.has_permissions)

Comment: It's giving me this error 

    @application_checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
NameError: name 'application_checks' is not defined

Comment: @NotLeo You should import it with `from nextcord.ext import application_checks`.

Comment: This has worked, But I now want it to send a message in chat telling to user they can't use the command due to insufficient permissions.

Comment: You can do that in `on_command_error(ctx, error)` and check for `isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions)` or alternatively you can create a function decorated with <command_name>.error that takrs error and ctx as parameter and do the same check i mentioned previously. But that's like a whole other question.